# Python pandas: Setting index value of dataframe to another dataframe as a column using multiple column conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes: `data_df` and `geo_dimension_df`.

I would like to take the index of `geo_dimension_df`, which I renamed to `id`, and make it a column on `data_df` called `geo_id`.

I'll be inserting both of these dataframes as tables into a database, and the `id` columns will be their primary keys while `geo_id` is a foreign key that will link `data_df` to `geo_dimension_df`.

As can be seen, the `cbsa` and `name` values can change over time. (Yuba City, CA -> Yuba City-Marysville, CA). Therefore, the `geo_dimension_df` is all the unique combinations of `cbsa` and `name`.

I need to compare the `cbsa` and `name` values on both dataframes and then when matching set `geo_dimension_df.id` as the `data_df.geo_id` value.

I tried using `merge` for a bit, but got confused, so now I'm trying with `apply` and looking at it like an Excel vlookup across multiple column values, but having no luck. The following is my attempt, but it's a bit gibberish...

```
data_df['geo_id'] = data_df[['cbsa', 'name']]
                        .apply(
                        lambda x, y: 
                        geo_dimension_df
                            .index[geo_dimension_df[['cbsa', 'name]]
                            .to_list()
                        == [x,y])
```

Below are the two original dataframes followed by the desired result. Thank you.

geo_dimension_df:

```
       cbsa                               name
id                           
  1   10180                        Abilene, TX
  2   10420                          Akron, OH
  3   10500                         Albany, GA
  4   10540                         Albany, OR
  5   10540                 Albany-Lebanon, OR
                     ...
519   49620                   York-Hanover, PA
520   49660  Youngstown-Warren-Boardman, OH-PA
521   49700                      Yuba City, CA
522   49700           Yuba City-Marysville, CA
523   49740                           Yuma, AZ
```

data_df:

```
             cbsa         name  month  year units_total
        id                                             
        1   10180  Abilene, TX      1  2004          22
        2   10180  Abilene, TX      2  2004          12
        3   10180  Abilene, TX      3  2004          44
        4   10180  Abilene, TX      4  2004          32
        5   10180  Abilene, TX      5  2004          21
                                 ...
    67145   49740  Yuma, AZ        12  2018          68
    67146   49740  Yuma, AZ         1  2019          86
    67147   49740  Yuma, AZ         2  2019          99
    67148   49740  Yuma, AZ         3  2019          99
    67149   49740  Yuma, AZ         4  2019          94
```

Desired Outcome:

data_df (with geo_id foreign key column added):

```
             cbsa         name  month  year units_total geo_id
        id                                             
        1   10180  Abilene, TX      1  2004          22      1
        2   10180  Abilene, TX      2  2004          12      1
        3   10180  Abilene, TX      3  2004          44      1
        4   10180  Abilene, TX      4  2004          32      1
        5   10180  Abilene, TX      5  2004          21      1
                                 ...
    67145   49740  Yuma, AZ        12  2018          68    523
    67146   49740  Yuma, AZ         1  2019          86    523
    67147   49740  Yuma, AZ         2  2019          99    523
    67148   49740  Yuma, AZ         3  2019          99    523
    67149   49740  Yuma, AZ         4  2019          94    523
```

Note: I'll be dropping `cbsa` and `name` from `data_df` after this, in case anybody is curious as to why I'm duplicating data.

Comment: Does `cbsa` ever change over time, or is it just their human-readable names that change? Could you left-join `data_df` and `geo_dimension_df` on `cbsa`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler, right, I should have been clearer, but the `cbsa` can change over time, though it's rare. The most notable example is Los Angeles, CA which changed from 31100 to 31080. I think having to compare across multiple column values is what makes this complicated. I might make a temp column that concatenates everything to reduce it to single column comparisons, but then that would cause some complications further down the line... I'll consider the tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, because the index is not a proper column, make it a column so that it can be used in a later `merge`:

```
geo_dimension_df['geo_id'] = geo_dimension_df.index
```

Next, join `data_df` and `geo_dimension_df`

```
data_df = pd.merge(data_df, 
                   geo_dimension_df['cbsa', 'name', 'geo_id'],
                   on=['cbsa', 'name'],
                   how='left')
```

Finally, drop the column you added to the `geo_dimension_df` at the start:

```
geo_dimension_df.drop('geo_id', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

After doing this, `geo_dimension_df`'s index column, `id`, will now appear on `data_df` under the column `geo_id`:

data_df:

```
         cbsa         name  month  year units_total geo_id
    id                                             
    1   10180  Abilene, TX      1  2004          22      1
    2   10180  Abilene, TX      2  2004          12      1
    3   10180  Abilene, TX      3  2004          44      1
    4   10180  Abilene, TX      4  2004          32      1
    5   10180  Abilene, TX      5  2004          21      1
                             ...
67145   49740  Yuma, AZ        12  2018          68    523
67146   49740  Yuma, AZ         1  2019          86    523
67147   49740  Yuma, AZ         2  2019          99    523
67148   49740  Yuma, AZ         3  2019          99    523
67149   49740  Yuma, AZ         4  2019          94    523
```

Comment: Great, thank you. This doesn't answer my question exactly but I was able to build off of this to get what I needed. I'd like to edit your answer to include the additional steps I took and then mark it as accepted so that you are credited with the SO points. If that's not a problem, then I can make the edit after work. Thanks again.